# Sitecore Collection Shards DB import failure

Tags: sitecore-client

We are doing the Sitecore 10.2 upgrade. We have exported and restored the Collection Shard0 and Shard1 into our local. We have successfully executed our upgrade script.

When we try to import the database again to Azure, we are getting the error.
[image]

Comment: You can connect Azure SQL Server on your local SSMS and import it.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595926/could-not-import-package-warning-sql72012-the-object-exists-in-the-target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue while I uploaded the DB backup on Azure BlobStorage and tried to restore it directly via Portal.

Connect the Azure SQL Server to your local SSMS. For that, you need to add your IP address to the Azure SQL Server Firewall rule.

1. To set a server-level IP firewall rule from the database overview
   page, select Set server firewall on the toolbar, as the following
   image shows
   [image]

   The **Networking** page for the server opens
2. Add a rule in the Firewall rules section to add the IP address of
   the computer that you're using, and then select Save. A server-level IP firewall rule is created for your current IP address.

[image]

**See the article:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql#from-the-database-overview-page

Once you are able to connect the Azure SQL server to the local SSMS then create the `BACPAC file` of the database instead of `.bak file` and try to restore the BACPAC file on Azure SQL Server.
See the blog post:

1. [How to create or export BACPAC file using SSMS?](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3925/How-to-create-or-export-BACPAC-file-using-SSMS-.html)
2. [How To Import Or Restore BACPAC File Using SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-import-or-restore-bacpac-file-from-ssms/)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to make a copy of the Shard databases in the same Azure resource group or a different Azure resource group.

This approach is a lot quicker than exporting the database as a Copy of the database takes less than 10 minutes as against an Export of a few hours.

you can use the following command in Azure to copy the database

```
CREATE DATABASE [NewDatabaseName] AS COPY OF [ProdDatabaseServerName].[CurrentDatabaseName];
```

You can now update the database to 10.2 using the Sitecore scripts and rename the database using the following command

```
ALTER Database [UpdatedDatabase] MODIFY NAME = [ProdDatabaseName]
```

Or you can update connection strings to use the new database.

Please check my upgrade guide for 10.2 for more details

https://sitecorepro.com/sitecore-10-2-upgrade-guide

Hope this helps